# How to make a quartz job create another job to execute after it?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am tying to implement the following algorithm with Quartz and not really sure if it can be done. This is my first attempt at using quartz.

- User notification Job - This job computes a monthly report and emails to a user, it expects a user id and other parameters that are used to generate the customized user report
- There are potentially 10,000+ of these reports that need to be generated

**Monthly Job to figure who needs reports Fires**

1. search the database to look for users that need to be sent a monthly report
2. for each user found create a jobDetail that will compute the monthly report and deliver it to report sender that takes care of sending the report
3. schedule each of the jobDetails from step 2 to execute right after this job finishes

What I have not been able to figure out.

1. How to make sure that monthly job executes in a single transaction so that all users that need a monthly report are identified and jobs are scheduled to notify them
2. How to schedule a job right away to execute right after the job that created them?

I am using Spring 3.2 an Quartz 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Nice use case for quartz usage.
You can try sheduling a new job from within the job class. This can be possibly with by creating a new jobdetail and trigger from inside execute() method.